# Accept Cookie from domain

Tags: android, cookies

I am trying to connect to foodEssentials API and it sends a cookie.

I am getting the error of `Cookie rejected: "BasicClientCookie ..."`

How do I deal with cookies coming in or is there any examples as I have looked around and found this [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

I am not sure what I should do. Does the browser handle the cookie or the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers handle server side cookies by themselves.

In case of Android application, developer need to explicitly handle the cookies. 
Here is an example of handling cookies : http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java

Comment: Thank you. I think I need more experience to build this application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CookieStore class of Apache http client. Somewhere in your code initialization, create a cookie store and http context:

```
    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

The cookie store will manage all the cookies as long as httpContext is alive.

So later, when doing a request, you just give the context to the httpClient:

```
AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(httpAgent);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String json = httpClient.execute(request, responseHandler, httpContext);
```

... and the cookies will be properly managed.

See [Android Http Client](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) and [Basic Cookie Store](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.html://).